# How to connect to hadoop remote cluster with java?

Tags: java, hadoop

Here is what i tried

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(
                        new URI("....com"), 
                        new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration());
                if (fileSystem instanceof DistributedFileSystem) {
                    System.out.println("HDFS is the underlying filesystem");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Other type of file system "
                            + fileSystem.getClass());
                }
```

I'm getting a weird error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
```

I don't even need the `apache commons`. I need `apache.hadoop` I initiated a class explicitly as `apache.hadoop` . Why am i getting this weird error ?  ? ?

Comment: Java libraries are known to link to each other... Sounds like you'll need to download the apache commons configuration library too

Comment: I have it in the class path just in case

Comment: Can you please describe how you are running this code?  Are you running a jar through the `hadoop jar` command or calling `java` directly or doing something else?